# Query With STR_TO_DATE() Giving 000-00-00

Tags: mysql

Here's my MySQL query:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(paid) AS yweek,
       STR_TO_DATE(YEARWEEK(paid), '%X%V') AS date,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM members
WHERE YEARWEEK(paid) >= YEARWEEK(curdate()) - 52
GROUP BY yweek
```

Here is the result:

```
 yweek     date     cnt
201429  0000-00-00  201
201430  0000-00-00  435
201431  0000-00-00  333
201432  0000-00-00  470
201433  0000-00-00  534
```

The `yweek` column and `cnt` column are fine, but the date column is always `0000-00-00`. The `paid` column in the members table is of the format (PHP) `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`, is of the column type `TIMESTAMP`, and here's an example: `2014-06-26 00:32:02`.

I have tried replacing `YEARWEEK(paid)` with `CAST(YEARWEEK(paid) AS CHAR(7))`, but that changes nothing.

Does the fact that I'm using a `TIMESTAMP` cause `STR_TO_DATE()` to give all zeros? I want to have the first date of the week along with `cnt`, the number of registrations in that week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is: you cannot get a date from a `yearweek`: there's 7 options, which one do you want?

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201429', '%X%V');
+-------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('201429', '%X%V') |
+-------------------------------+
| 0000-00-00                    |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If we add a 'day of the week' (%w) to it, it magically begins to worK:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2014290', '%X%V%w');
+----------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2014290', '%X%V%w') |
+----------------------------------+
| 2014-07-20                       |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But: this means you have to choose the day of the week you want *statically*, because the original date is no longer in a yearweek.

Of course, in this case, you might as well have done this:

```
SELECT 
       YEARWEEK(paid) AS yweek,
       DATE(paid) AS date,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
....
```

...  but I assumed this was just an illustration of the problem getting a date of a yearweek string. If not, then this second solution will just work for you.